# Google Map Android and iOS Xamarin: Create Close Polygon on random tapped coordinates

Tags: android, ios, google-maps

Im using Google Map on Xamarin Android and iOS

Im trying to create a close polygon from random tap coordinates.

Android like:

```
var options = new PolygonOptions();
                        options.InvokeFillColor(int.Parse("80000000", System.Globalization.NumberStyles.HexNumber));
                        options.InvokeStrokeColor(int.Parse("000000", System.Globalization.NumberStyles.HexNumber));
                        options.InvokeStrokeWidth(2);
options.AddAll(listOfPosition); //list of tapped coordinates
googleMap.AddPolygon(options);
```

iOS like:

```
var polygon = new Polygon();
                    polygon.Path = path; // this is my list of tapped coordinates
                    polygon.StrokeWidth = 2;
                    polygon.StrokeColor = UIColor.Black;
                    polygon.FillColor = UIColor.FromRGBA(0, 0, 0, 0.3f);
polygon.Map = mapView;
```

Let say I have tapped coordinates randomly like this :

```
Debug|LOCATION:: 37.9115841998119 : -122.566957734525
Debug|LOCATION:: 37.9117754470967 : -122.561504803598
Debug|LOCATION:: 37.9085008969633 : -122.566276118159
Debug|LOCATION:: 37.9086561762004 : -122.562640719116
Debug|LOCATION:: 37.9102216477146 : -122.561550065875
Debug|LOCATION:: 37.9098513127501 : -122.567805983126
Debug|LOCATION:: 37.9123967989511 : -122.564518935978
```

How can I make it close polygon without intersecting lines inside even may tap coordinates reached 100 position data.? Any Idea or Computation? Thanks advance..

[image]

Answer (score 1):

You don't have to compute locally, Use Shapes API of Google maps

- https://developer.xamarin.com/guides/android/platform_features/maps_and_location/maps/part_2_-_maps_api/#Drawing_on_the_Map
- https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/android-api/shapes

To sort the points locally for closed polygon

- https://stackoverflow.com/a/7369943/2700586

Reference:
http://geomalgorithms.com/a10-_hull-1.html

Comment: I already do the api.. the problem is how can make it close polygon on random coordinates tapped.. it intersect each line depends on location sorting..

Comment: You have to use PolygonOptions not the polygon, itself

Comment: I use PolygonOptions for Xamarin android. above code is for xamarin iOS google map version

Comment: Refer this https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15615996/how-to-draw-filled-polygon-in-google-maps-sdk-for-ios

Comment: thanks but doesn't help much.. I need some computation to connect all position dots into close polygon something like sorting the list of coordinates on the map. .

Comment: your edit answer seems nice ref: https://stackoverflow.com/a/7369943/2700586
 gonna take a study and try thx

Answer (score 0):

Here's the solution :)

You need to get the most Left and most Right on Lat and Lon.

get the min and max latitude.

[image]

Draw a line and seperate first the lower points and the higher points

Check points if its on higher or lower by equation of line.

```
public static bool CheckIsUpperCoordinate(PositionData a, PositionData b, PositionData c)
        {
            var position = Math.Sign((b.Latitude - a.Latitude) * (c.Longitude - a.Longitude) - (b.Longitude - a.Longitude) * (c.Latitude - a.Latitude));

            return position > 0 ? true : false; //true if upper , false if lower position
        }
```

Now sort lowerlist and upperlist by its longitude.

```
var lowerPosition = lowerPositionList.OrderBy(x => x.Longitude).ToList();
var higherPosition = higherPositionList.OrderByDescending(x => x.Longitude).ToList();
```

And connect all points from this sequence left most -> lower points list -> right most -> upper points list

```
path.AddLatLon(leftMost.Latitude, leftMost.Longitude);

foreach (PositionData lowerData in lowerPosition)
{
       path.AddLatLon(lowerData.Latitude, lowerData.Longitude);
}
path.AddLatLon(rightMost.Latitude, rightMost.Longitude);

foreach (PositionData higherData in higherPosition)
{
       path.AddLatLon(higherData.Latitude, higherData.Longitude);

}
path.AddLatLon(leftMost.Latitude, leftMost.Longitude);
```

wrap it on polygon

```
var polygon = new Polygon();
                    polygon.Path = path;
                    polygon.StrokeWidth = 2;
                    polygon.StrokeColor = UIColor.Black;
                    polygon.FillColor = UIColor.FromRGBA(0, 0, 0, 0.3f);
  polygon.Map = mapView;
```

Hope it may help someone :)

I appreciated my Math Teacher after this task. lol xd