# Google Maps SDK for iOS camera boundaries

Tags: ios, google-maps, google-maps-sdk-ios

Is there a way to set boundaries on the camera, so the zoom is automatically set like in the Android API?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There is a similar question here:

[How to setRegion with google maps sdk for iOS?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15040409/how-to-setregion-with-google-maps-sdk-for-ios)

There is also a feature request to add this to the SDK here:

https://code.google.com/p/gmaps-api-issues/issues/detail?id=4950