# -[GMSMapView region]: unrecognized selector - Issue with Google Maps SDK for iOS

Tags: ios, google-maps, mkmapview, google-maps-sdk-ios

I'm here because I have a problem with the Google Maps SDK for iOS.

My map is running properly, and everything works fine.

In my project, I'm trying to get a dynamic zoom between 2 markers, in order to see them in the same frame. So here is my code (I get it somewhere in stackoverflow too) :

```
- (NSInteger)getZoomLevel
{
    MKMapView *map = (MKMapView *)mapView_;
    CLLocationDegrees longitudeDelta = map.region.span.longitudeDelta;
    CGFloat mapWidthInPixels = map.bounds.size.width;
    double zoomScale = longitudeDelta * 85445659.44705395 * M_PI / (180.0 * mapWidthInPixels);
    double zoomer = 20 - log2(zoomScale);
    if ( zoomer < 0 ) zoomer = 0;
    return (NSInteger)zoomer;
}
```

And this is how I call it :

```
GMSCameraUpdate *zoomCamera = [GMSCameraUpdate zoomIn];
    [mapView_ animateWithCameraUpdate:zoomCamera];

    CLLocationCoordinate2D myPosition = CLLocationCoordinate2DMake(mapView_.myLocation.coordinate.latitude, mapView_.myLocation.coordinate.longitude);
    GMSCameraUpdate *myPositionCam = [GMSCameraUpdate setTarget:myPosition];
    [mapView_ animateToZoom:[self getZoomLevel]];
    [mapView_ animateWithCameraUpdate:myPositionCam];
```

The point is to see 2 markers in the same frame.

This is what I have when I try to run it :

```
-[GMSMapView region]: unrecognized selector sent to instance 0x210527e0
```

Any ideas ? Or if anyone get a best sample code to get the right zoom.

Thanks !! :)

Comment: Why are you casting your `GMSMapView` instance to `MKMapView`? It doesn't inherit from `MKMapView`. And it's natural it doesn't respond to `MKMapView`'s messages. Why are you making assumptions instead of reading the [documentation](https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/ios/reference/interface_g_m_s_map_view)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The sample code which you got from [How to calculate GMSCamera zoom](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14354450/how-to-calculate-gmscamera-zoom) was showing how it could be done with an `MKMapView` - the intention being to adapt it to the equivalent code for a `GMSMapView` (not using the code directly).

There's a more comprehensive answer (specifically for `GMSMapView`) here:

[How to setRegion with google maps sdk for iOS?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15040409/how-to-setregion-with-google-maps-sdk-for-ios)

However, both of those questions were asked before Google added a `fitBounds` method which should be able to be used instead of writing your own code:

https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/ios/reference/interface_g_m_s_camera_update

I noticed though that [somebody reported](https://stackoverflow.com/a/16217785/148241) that `fitBounds` didn't work for them - so see how you go.

Answer (score 1):

The problem is that you are accessing the region method of the `GMSMapViewRegion` which doesn't exist (`map.region` in line: `CLLocationDegrees longitudeDelta = map.region.span.longitudeDelta;`).

You are using code that is meant for Apple's map implementation in Google's which is incompatible.